# How to efficiently handle asynchronous operations in python?

Tags: python, asynchronous, error-handling, concurrency, python-asyncio

*What I tried:*

I attempted to implement asynchronous operations in Python using asyncio, specifically aiming to leverage the power of concurrent task execution. My code involves multiple asynchronous functions managed by asyncio.gather. The goal was to achieve parallelism and efficiency in handling various tasks concurrently.

```py
import asyncio

async def task_one():
    # Asynchronous code for task one

async def task_two():
    # Asynchronous code for task two


try:
    await asyncio.gather(task_one(), task_two(), ...)
except Exception as e:
    # Handling exceptions during task execution
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
```

*What happened:*

While executing the asynchronous tasks, I encountered a challenge related to error handling. When an exception occurred within one of the tasks, it disrupted the entire event loop. This behavior made it difficult to gracefully handle errors and continue with the remaining tasks.

I expected a more resilient error-handling mechanism that would allow me to identify and address errors within individual tasks without affecting the entire process. My current implementation falls short in providing the desired robustness.

I'm seeking guidance on improving my approach to error handling in asyncio, ensuring that the execution of other tasks is not disrupted in the event of an exception.

Comment: ```try except``` should be within task_one and task_two, not outside. Although note that ```Exception as e``` is not considered good practice - some linters warn when you do this. You should have an idea where and why the errors will occur so that you are more narrowly handling the expected errors.

Comment: @jwal, the `try-except` does not make a difference. the code broke because of the ellipses `...`.

Comment: @D.L I expect you have misread the illustration of the issue as the ... is not the only syntax issue.

Comment: @jwal,  you are correct.  In the answer i post, i show that the errors can be handled nicely in the async code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

In the code in the question, this format would work nicely.

```py
import asyncio

async def task_one():
    try:
        print(hello)    
    except Exception as e:
        print('exception found:', e)
    

async def task_two():
    print("Two")

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(task_one(), task_two())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

which returns this:

```
exception found: name 'hello' is not defined
Two
```

the error handling (if needed would then be internal to each function).